# scala printing word length histogram scala

Tags: scala, flatmap

I am taking in as input a set of lines and  keep track of the distribution of word lengths. Extra white space including newlines in the input does not matter. After the end of the input is reached, output is  a text-based histogram of the distribution of word lengths: 
eg : "Hey How are you hey am good"

Ouput :
1 - 0,  2 - 1, 
3 - 5,
4 - 1,
5 - 0

where(first char is length of words and second is no of words of that length).
I have written

```
val lines = scala.io.Source.stdin.getLines
val words = lines.flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
```

I want to group words of same length and then store them in a iterator or map

```
val list2 = words.groupby(e.length => e.length).mapValues(_.length)
```

does not give me the desired result.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've pretty much got it, but you need `groupBy(e => e.length)`.  The left side (`e`) of the anonymous function (`e => e.length`), should be a variable name that will be used for each item in the collection (ie, each word).  So `e` is a word, and we group according to the lengths of the words.

(Also, `groupBy` has a capital "B").

```
val list2 = words.groupBy(e => e.length).mapValues(_.length)
```

If you want the output like you described, you could follow it up with:

```
val vectorOfLengths = (1 to list2.keys.max).map(length => list2.getOrElse(length, 0))
// Vector(0, 1, 5, 1)
println(vectorOfLengths.zipWithIndex.map{case (count, length) => f"${length+1} - $count" }.mkString(", "))
// 1 - 0, 2 - 1, 3 - 5, 4 - 1
```

Or, hey, how about visually?

```
for ((count, length) <- vectorOfLengths.zipWithIndex)
  println(f"${length+1}: ${"#" * count}")
//   1:
//   2: #
//   3: #####
//   4: #
```

Just for fun, how about a visual histogram of [Alice in Wonderland](http://www.gutenberg.org/cache/epub/11/pg11.txt)?

```
val aliceLines = io.Source.fromFile("/Users/dhg/texts/alice.txt").getLines.toVector
val aliceWords = aliceLines.flatMap(_.split("\\W+"))
val aliceHist = aliceWords.groupBy(_.length).mapValues(_.length)
val aliceLengths = (1 to aliceHist.keys.max).map(aliceHist.getOrElse(_, 0))
for ((count, length) <- aliceLengths.zipWithIndex)
  println(f"${length+1}%2s: ${"#" * (count/100)}")

//     1: ###################
//     2: ##################################################
//     3: ############################################################################
//     4: #############################################################
//     5: ###################################
//     6: ######################
//     7: ##################
//     8: ########
//     9: ######
//    10: ###
//    11: #
//    12:
//    13:
//    14:
//    15:
//    16:
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, Scala collections provide groupBy method, in case of [Seq](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Seq@groupBy[K](f:A=%3EK):scala.collection.immutable.Map[K,Repr]) it looks like this:

```
def groupBy[K](f: (A) ⇒ K): immutable.Map[K, Seq[A]]
```

which means it applies a function to every element in the list and groups them based on the result. To group words by their length, the function should take a string and return it length:

```
//words: Seq[String] = Seq(a, b, c, dd, eee, fff)
val byLength = words.groupBy{(w:String) => w.length}//Map(2 -> Seq(dd), 
                                                    //    1 -> Seq(a, b, c), 
                                                    //    3 -> Seq(eee, fff))
```

Or you may put it a bit shorter, omitting parameter type declaration, the compiler will understand you:

```
val byLength = words.groupBy(w => w.length)
```

or even defining the anonymous function with an underscore placeholder:

```
val byLength = words.groupBy(_.length) //same thing
```

Now you can get words with specified length:

```
val singleCharacterWords = byLength(1) //Seq(a, b, c)
```

or check if the map contains some length

```
byLength.contains(1) //true
byLength.contains(5) //false
```

or iterate through all keys:

```
byLength.foreach{
  case (length:Int, wordsGroup:Seq[String]) => 
    println(s"Words with length $length : ${wordsGroup.mkString(" ")}")
}
//Words with length 2 : dd
//Words with length 1 : b c
//Words with length 3 : eee fff
```

see [Map](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.collection.Map) for that.

Comment: Sorry, but "here's why what you're doing doesn't work" is a lot more useful than "here's some code that kind of does a similar thing, oh also you have to scroll horizontally to see it".

Comment: You don't have to scroll, the code required is "words.group(_.length)", it's perfectly visible, and that's the answer to "how do I group a list of words by their length". The rest is console output to illustrate how it works, which is not essential.

Comment: Though you're probably right here, edited that lazy answer into a more detailed one.